# Purpose of the Action interface that extends the ActionListener in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am currently learning Swing through [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594479). It says this about the Action interface:

> To simplify event handling, the Swing library extends the original ActionListener interface
>   with the Action interface to store visual attributes with the event handler. This allows the creation
>   of event handlers independent of visual components. Then, when the Action is later associated
>   with a component, the component automatically gets information (such as a button label)
>   directly from the event handler. This includes notification of updates for the label when the
>   Action is modified. The AbstractAction and TextAction classes are implementations of this
>   concept.

Can somebody please explain what this text means?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if means that properties of the `Action` can be shared by one (or more) components, so you only need to set the property once.

For example you can use the `Action` to create a `JButton` and a `JMenuItem`. Then if you change the state of the `Action`, the state of the button and menu item will change at the same time.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information and working examples. The example specifically demonstrates how you can change the enabled state of the Action and both components will be affected.